# What does a fitted value mean in dshw forecasting package?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a double seasonal data. I wrote the following code to find the best fit model and find fitted values:

> orders <- read.csv("DataForR.csv", header = TRUE),
>   NumOrders <- orders$Orders,
> > period <- orders$Period,
>   OrderTimeSeries <- msts(NumOrders,seasonal.periods=c(24,7*24)),
>   fit2 <- dshw(OrderTimeSeries,24,168,336,alpha=NULL,beta=NULL,gamma=NULL,omega=NULL,phi=NULL,lambda=NULL,armethod=TRUE,model=NULL),

my original time series plot is as follows:
[image]

but the fitted values are as follows:

[image]

I wonder what does a fitted value mean? does it mean using the fitted model, the forecast values for the training dataset are fitted data? how can I have both series in one plot so I can better compare their trends? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fitted values correspond to an optimal 1-step ahead forecast.

See: http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf